# How to select all sublayers in one click in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Illustrator sometimes in one layer we have to draw many things. and I want to select them all in a fast way. Neither double click on the main layer or shift click the sublayers works, How can I select many sublayers in Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: You are supposed to click on the circle on the right

Comment: :(  :'( So long I waited.   Thank you.

Comment: Same here, too much complexity. There's no need to have all these layers.  If you want to organise things, use groups.

Comment: @BillyKerr Group creates problem in After Effects. Sometimes you need only one layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joojaa answered in comments, but...

To select a layer, sublayer, or object via the **Layers Panel** you need to click the **little circle to the right** of the layer/object. That is the "select" trigger.

You can <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click or <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>-click the circle for multiple objects.

---

Highlighting Layers/sublayers/objects in the Layers Panel only allows you to perform operations *in the panel itself* - via the icons at the bottom of the panel, or the panel menu - such as duplicating or deleting things. Highlights in the Layers Panel don't *actually* select anything in terms of what's on any artboard(s).